# Анимация PageViewController

Tags: swift

Есть PageViewController, который листается вправо-влево. На первой странице находится фотография. Нужно чтобы при пролистывании на вторую страницу фотография плавно уменьшалась. То есть чем дальше я перелистываю, тем сильнее уменьшается картинка.
Я могу сделать анимацию только когда полностью перешел на вторую страницу, а вот чтобы уменьшать картинку в процессе перелистыванию - для меня это непосильная задача. Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кратко - с кастомной анимацией и настройкой анимации отдельных элементов у `UIPageViewController` туго, лучше использовать для этого `UICollectionView`.

Во-первых, нет встроенного способа получения смещения страницы, для доступа к имеющемуся `UIScrollView` приходится делать нечто подобное

```
let scrollView = view.subviews.first { $0 is UIScrollView } as! UIScrollView
scrollView.delegate = self
```

После этого можно использовать метод делегата для получения смещения

```
extension PageViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // ...
    }
    
}
```

Во-вторых, встроенная анимация `UIPageViewController` не дает адекватно управлять масштабированием картинки, при обратном листании происходят резкие скачки масштаба

Полный пример

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    
    var pages = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        
        let p1 = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc1")
        let p2 = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")

        pages.append(p1)
        pages.append(p2)

        setViewControllers([p1], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        
        let scrollView = view.subviews.first { $0 is UIScrollView } as! UIScrollView
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func scaleImageOnFirstPage(with scrollViewOffset: CGFloat) {
        let minScale: CGFloat = 0.5
        
        let currentViewController = viewControllers!.first!
        let imageViewController = pages.first as! ImageViewController

        // on each page scroll offset always starts with screen's width
        // decreasing when moving to prev page anf increasing when moving to next page
        
        if currentViewController is ImageViewController {
            let scale = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / scrollViewOffset
        
            if scale <= 1.0 {
                imageViewController.scaleImageView(scale: scale)
            }
        } else {
            let index = pages.firstIndex(of: currentViewController)!
            
            if index == 1 {
                let delta = (scrollViewOffset / UIScreen.main.bounds.width) - minScale
                let scale = 1.0 - delta
                
                if scale <= 1.0 && scale >= minScale {
                    imageViewController.scaleImageView(scale: scale)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

extension PageViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scaleImageOnFirstPage(with: scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    }
    
}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController)-> UIViewController? {
       
        let cur = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController)!

        // if you prefer to NOT scroll circularly, simply add here:
        if cur == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        var prev = (cur - 1) % pages.count
        if prev < 0 {
            prev = pages.count - 1
        }
        return pages[prev]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController)-> UIViewController? {
         
        let cur = pages.firstIndex(of: viewController)!

        // if you prefer to NOT scroll circularly, simply add here:
        if cur == (pages.count - 1) {
            return nil
        }

        let nxt = abs((cur + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nxt]
    }

}
```

Класс контроллера с картинкой

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    func scaleImageView(scale: CGFloat) {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    }

}
```

Comment: А расскажите пожалуйста как сделать то что мне нужно через UICollectionView

Comment: @AlexeyGolenkov это уже другой вопрос, если на текущий вопрос я ответил, то поставьте возле него галку

Comment: Поставил, спасибо
Как мне получить ответ на вопрос про UICollectionView? Новую тему создать или Вы здесь сможете ответить?

Comment: @AlexeyGolenkov для начала погуглите например `uicollectionview carousel swift`, есть готовые решения